# How do i change from the default look of a list activity list?

Tags: android

I have created a list activity class and made an array adapter. However, how would i change the appearance of the list it generates when run. As in how do i change the colour, style etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `styles.xml` in your `values` folder then do something like

```
<!-- ListView -->
<style name="List_Item" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/list_item_bg</item>  // if you have a drawable you want to use
    //add whatever other attributes you want
</style>
```

then in the xml with your `ListView` delcare your style

```
 <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_plate"
    style="@style/List_Item"/>    //here you implement your style
```

Comment: no, i cant access xml i don't think because i'm using an array adapter from my list activity. Im not using a listview.

Comment: You should still have a `ListView` that you set an `adapter on`. You also should be specifying a `TextView` in your adapter. You can make that a single `TextView` in its own `layout` file and apply the `style` to that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Theme & Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and xml attributes for [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or any View inside your ListView